# error installing secrets because of missing openSSL bindings in python Python 3.11.5

Tags: python, pip, openssl, virtualenv, setuptools

I have been trying to install `secrets` using pip to make a basic password generator and manager. I have already installed `setuptools(both latest and an older version)`, `cryptography` and `pyopenssl`, but I am still getting an error which looks like this

```
(virtualenv) PS C:\Users\apoorvpathak\Desktop\cli-password-manager> pip install cryptography secrets
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography in c:\users\apoorvpathak\desktop\cli-password-manager\virtualenv\lib\site-packages (41.0.4)
Collecting secrets
  Using cached secrets-1.0.2.tar.gz (7.9 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [26 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 10, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'OpenSSL'

      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\apoorvpathak\Desktop\cli-password-manager\virtualenv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\apoorvpathak\Desktop\cli-password-manager\virtualenv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\apoorvpathak\Desktop\cli-password-manager\virtualenv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\apoorvpathak\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0hq3ammt\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 355, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\apoorvpathak\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0hq3ammt\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\apoorvpathak\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0hq3ammt\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 507, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\apoorvpathak\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0hq3ammt\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 12, in <module>
      ImportError: Installing this module requires OpenSSL python bindings
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
```

I have tried Installing and Uninstalling `python`, `setuptools`, `cryptography`, `pyopenssl`, I deleted and created several virtual environments too, and it did not work in any of them.

Is there any way I can successfully install `secrets`.

I read an article which said not to use secrets if I am getting this error, so what alternatives do I have incase all fails?

Comment: What version of Python you are running on

Comment: @Satya it's written in the title of the post v3.11.5

Comment: Isn't the `secrets` module you are looking for the one from the standard library? You don't have to install anything in such case. https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/secrets/ "Scripts to manage LDAP users and change LDAP passwords"  Released: Jun 1, **2012**. I'm sure it's not what you want.